# Bootstrap, how to rearrange input tag when on mobile view?

Tags: bootstrap-4

So currently my input view is like this (for desktop view, which is good):

[image]

But when i put in mobile view it became like this (which is bad):

[image]

My goal is to make the the input (see below) when in mobile view. How to achieve this goal?

text1

text11

text2

text22

text3

text33

**Bootstrap HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="text1">text1</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text1">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="text2">text2</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text2">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="text3">text3</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text3">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="text11">text11</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text11">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="text22">text22</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text22">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="text33">text33</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text33">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle sample here](https://jsfiddle.net/re0sgx6k/)

Comment: Ok, so we know what you have and we know what you want (of course it can be done). What did you try?

Comment: I would probably do (3) 2-column rows instead of (2) 3-row columns.

Comment: I tried using d-flex but doesnt work out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, what was wrong in your code is that you logically divided 2 sets of columns, column#1 contains [text1, text2, text3] while column#2 contains [text11, text22, text33]. You can think of it as 1 set of column as 1 single object, therefore you have 2 objects. Now when when the view shrinks, the 2 objects would be concatenated with each other, producing [text1, text2, text3] + [text11, text22, text33].

For me, my approach would be is instead of grouping them into columns, why not group them into rows, with each row containing [text1, text11], then [text2, text22], and lastly [text3, text33]. There are multiple ways to achieve this. Here are some options I can think of.

**Using row-cols** https://jsfiddle.net/qnkbgwu0/

```
<div class="container">
  <form>

    <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-2">
      <div class="col form-group">
        <label for="text1">text1</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text1">
      </div>
      <div class="col form-group">
        <label for="text11">text11</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text11">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-2">
      <div class="col form-group">
        <label for="text2">text2</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text2">
      </div>
      <div class="col form-group">
        <label for="text22">text22</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text22">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-2">
      <div class="col form-group">
        <label for="text3">text3</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text3">
      </div>
      <div class="col form-group">
        <label for="text33">text33</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text33">
      </div>
    </div>

  </form>
</div>
```

**Using d-flex** https://jsfiddle.net/1ezybfq3/

```
<div class="container">
  <form>

    <div class="d-md-flex justify-content-between">
      <div class="flex-fill mx-2 form-group">
        <label for="text1">text1</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text1">
      </div>
      <div class="flex-fill mx-2 form-group">
        <label for="text11">text11</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text11">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="d-md-flex justify-content-between">
      <div class="flex-fill mx-2 form-group">
        <label for="text2">text2</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text2">
      </div>
      <div class="flex-fill mx-2 form-group">
        <label for="text22">text22</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text22">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="d-md-flex justify-content-between">
      <div class="flex-fill mx-2 form-group">
        <label for="text3">text3</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text3">
      </div>
      <div class="flex-fill mx-2 form-group">
        <label for="text33">text33</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text33">
      </div>
    </div>

  </form>
</div>
```

**Using hardcoded col size per row** https://jsfiddle.net/zwcLg201/

```
<!-- trimmed snippet -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
    <label for="text1">text1</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text1">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
    <label for="text11">text11</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text11">
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want more reference, then I strongly suggest this reading materials:

- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid
- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/flex/

Comment: The row-cols is exactly what I suggested but I wasn't going to write the code for him.

Answer (score -1):

Check the documentation for Flex-Bootstrap - Order.  (.order-0, .order-1 - should help set the order you want )  To activate the desired order for mobile, say 576px, you could add the classes .order-sm-1 etc.

Comment: tried the d-flex but i wonder why it doesn't work https://jsfiddle.net/re0sgx6k/1/

Comment: @stu1612 - Is this an answer or a suggestion?  A suggestion belongs in a comment.